# Rich TextBlock in ListViewItem Text Wrapping

Tags: xaml, uwp, word-wrap

I have a RichTextBlock in a ListViewItem in a ListView. I can't for the life of me findout why the text wrapping on the RichTextBlock won't apply.
XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MessagesScroller" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
            <ListView x:Name="Messages" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

C#

```
ListViewItem listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
                    listviewitem.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                    listviewitem.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                    listviewitem.Tag = message.Id;
                    StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
                    stack.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                    stack.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                    Image Avatar = new Image();
                    Avatar.Height = 50;
                    Avatar.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    Avatar.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/" + message.User.Id + "/" + message.User.Avatar + ".jpg"));
                    stack.Children.Add(Avatar);
                    StackPanel innerstack = new StackPanel();
                    innerstack.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                    StackPanel MsgData = new StackPanel();
                    MsgData.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                    #region RichTextBlock
                    RichTextBlock user = new RichTextBlock();
                    user.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords;
                    Paragraph userPara = new Paragraph();
                    Run run1 = new Run();
                    run1.Text = message.User.Username;
                    userPara.Inlines.Add(run1);
                    user.Blocks.Add(userPara);
                    #endregion

                    MsgData.Children.Add(user);

                    #region RichTextBlock
                    RichTextBlock timestamp = new RichTextBlock();
                    Paragraph timePara = new Paragraph();
                    Run run2 = new Run();
                    run2.Text = message.Timestamp.Month.ToString() + "/" + message.Timestamp.Day + " at " + message.Timestamp.Hour.ToString() + ":";
                    if (message.Timestamp.Minute < 9)
                    {
                        run2.Text += "0";
                    }
                    run2.Text += message.Timestamp.Minute.ToString();
                    timestamp.Foreground = GetSolidColorBrush("#FF333333");
                    timePara.Inlines.Add(run2);
                    timestamp.Blocks.Add(timePara);
                    timestamp.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0);
                    #endregion

                    MsgData.Children.Add(timestamp);
                    innerstack.Children.Add(MsgData);

                    #region RichTextBlock
                    RichTextBlock txtblock = new RichTextBlock();
                    txtblock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords;
                    Paragraph txtPara = new Paragraph();
                    Run run3 = new Run();
                    run3.Text = message.Content;
                    txtPara.Inlines.Add(run3);

                    txtblock.Blocks.Add(txtPara);

                    foreach (SharedModels.Embed embed in message.Embeds)
                    {
                        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
                        if (embed.title != null)
                        {
                            Run title = new Run();
                            title.Text = embed.title + "\n";
                            paragraph.Inlines.Add(title);
                        }
                        if (embed.Description != null)
                        {
                            Run desc = new Run();
                            desc.Text = embed.Description + "\n";
                            paragraph.Inlines.Add(desc);
                        }
                        if (embed.Thumbnail.Url != null)
                        {
                            InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer();
                            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(embed.Thumbnail.ProxyUrl));
                            Image image = new Image();
                            image.Height = 300;
                            image.Source = bi;
                            container.Child = image;
                            paragraph.Inlines.Add(container);
                        }
                        txtblock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
                    }

                    foreach (SharedModels.Attachment attach in message.Attachments)
                    {
                        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
                        Run run = new Run();
                        run.Text = attach.Filename;
                        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(attach.Url));
                        Image image = new Image();
                        image.Height = 300;
                        image.Source = bi;
                        InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer();
                        container.Child = image;
                        paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
                        paragraph.Inlines.Add(container);
                        txtblock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
                    }
                    #endregion

                    innerstack.Children.Add(txtblock);
                    stack.Children.Add(innerstack);
                    listviewitem.Content = stack;

                    #region Flyout
                    Flyout flyout = new Flyout();
                    StackPanel flyoutcontent = new StackPanel();
                    flyoutcontent.Margin = new Thickness(-10);
                    /*Button AddRection = new Button()
                    {
                        Content = "Add Reaction",
                        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
                    };
                    flyoutcontent.Children.Add(AddRection);
                    Button Pin = new Button()
                    {
                        Content = "Pin",
                        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
                    };
                    flyoutcontent.Children.Add(Pin);*/
                    /*Button Edit = new Button()
                    {
                        Content = "Edit",
                        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                        Tag = message.Id
                    };
                    Edit.Click += EditMessage;
                    flyoutcontent.Children.Add(Edit);*/
                    Button Delete = new Button()
                    {
                        Content = "Delete",
                        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                        Tag = message.Id
                    };
                    Delete.Click += DeleteThisMessage;
                    flyoutcontent.Children.Add(Delete);
                    flyout.Content = flyoutcontent;
                    listviewitem.ContextFlyout = flyout;
                    listviewitem.RightTapped += OpenRightTapFlyout;
                    listviewitem.Holding += OpenHoldingFlyout;
                    #endregion

                    Messages.Items.Add(listviewitem);
```

I have uprooted my entire program to use StackPanels instead but that didn't help

Answer (score 2):

You used `StackPanel` for your layout and set the [`Orientation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.orientation) property to `Horizontal` for the `StackPanel`.  `StackPanel` is size to its children. So it seems like the reason is that you don't set the `Width` property for the `RichTextBlock`. The `width` of `RichTextBlock` size to its content, StackPanel`size to`RichTextBlock`, it may not wrap.

You may have several ways to resolve this:

- Set `width` property for the `RichTextBlock`.

  ```
  RichTextBlock txtblock = new RichTextBlock();
  txtblock.Width = 300;
  txtblock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords;
  ```
- Remove the `orientation`  property for the `StackPanel` if you don't need such a layout.

  ```
   //stack.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
  ```
- Or you may use a [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid) instead. Grid may better help you define the layout. You may define the image and `RichTextBlock` layout as followings.

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Image Source="Assets/caffe1.jpg" Height="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
      <RichTextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
          <Paragraph>
              <Run FontStyle="Italic">sample text todemonstrate some properties.demonstrate some properties.demonstrate some properties.demonstrate some properties.
                          demonstrate some properties.demonstrate some properties.demonstrate some properties.demonstrate some properties.demonstrate some properties.
              </Run> 
          </Paragraph>
      </RichTextBlock>
  </Grid>
  ```